# mongodb $elemMatch with regex return only one element from array of a single document

Tags: mongodb

I want a string search in a nested array. For every document, it only returns the first matched array element though there are a more matched array element in a document. 
Mongo structure:

```
{
"bookmarkId" : "5b9ce0be489cdc34ffa9d650",
"notes" : [
    {
        "noteId" : "5b9ce0be489cdc34ffa9d650",
        "note" : "number"
    },
    {
        "noteId" : "5b9ce4ba489cdc34ffa9d653",
        "note" : "hhgjjkg"
    },
    {
        "noteId" : "5b9ce4cc489cdc34ffa9d654",
        "note" : "test"
    },
    {
        "noteId" : "5b9ce8a2a3219b3f166cc5de",
        "note" : "hhgjjkg"
    },
    {
        "noteId" : "5b9cf703a3219b3f166cc5ea",
        "note" : "number"
    }
],
"userId" : "5aeae1da9072420ff68bd48e"
}
```

The mongodb query is :

```
db.bookmark.find({"userId" : "5aeae1da9072420ff68bd48e","notes.note":new RegExp('hgjj', 'i')},{_id:0,bookmarkId:1,notes:{$elemMatch:{note:new RegExp('hgjj', 'i')}}})
```

Though the 2nd and 4th element match the query, it only returns the first element.
Output:

```
{ "bookmarkId" : "5b9ce0be489cdc34ffa9d650", "notes" : [ { "noteId" : "5b9ce4ba489cdc34ffa9d653", "note" : "hhgjjkg" } ] }
```

How to get all the matched element from mongodb?

Comment: Once the following ticket has been resolved you can use `$filter` for that: //https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the mongoDB documentation of the [find projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#find-projection) you can't use $elemMatch to filter elements.

Instead you can concider to use an aggregation:

```
db.bookmark.aggregate([
{
    $unwind: '$notes'
},
{
    $match: {"userId" : "5aeae1da9072420ff68bd48e","notes.note":new RegExp('hgjj', 'i')}
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$bookmarkId',
        notes: {$push : '$notes'}
     }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        bookmarkId: '$_id',
        notes: '$notes'
     }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

> **Definition $elemMatch**:
>   The $elemMatch operator limits the contents of
>   an  field from the query results to contain only the first
>   element matching the $elemMatch condition.

So if you use the elemMatch operator to compute a projection, then only the first element in the nested array that matches will be projected.

To me it looks like you wanted to create a new "notes" array containing only the matching nested documents. One way to do this is with grouping via the aggregation framework:

```
db.bookmark.aggregate([
{
    "$match": {
        "userId" : "5aeae1da9072420ff68bd48e",
        "notes.note":new RegExp('hgjj', 'i')
    }        
}, 
{
    "$unwind": {
        "path": "$notes"
    }
}, 
{
    "$match": {
        "notes.note": new RegExp('hgjj', 'i')
    }
}, 
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "bookmark_id": {
            "$first": "$bookmarkId"
        },
        "notes": {
            "$push": "$notes"
        }        
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "bookmark_id": 1,
        "notes": 1
    }
}
])
```

yields:

```
{ "bookmark_id" : "5b9ce0be489cdc34ffa9d650", "notes" : [ { "noteId" : "5b9ce4ba489cdc34ffa9d653", "note" : "hhgjjkg" } ] }
{ "bookmark_id" : "5b9ce0be489cdc34ffa9d650", "notes" : [ { "noteId" : "5b9ce8a2a3219b3f166cc5de", "note" : "hhgjjkg" } ] }
{ "bookmark_id" : "5b9ce0be489cdc34ffa9d650", "notes" : [ { "noteId" : "5b9ce4ba489cdc34ffa9d653", "note" : "hhgjjkg" }, { "noteId" : "5b9ce8a2a3219b3f166cc5de", "note" : "hhgjjkg" } ] }
```